# understanding "dispatch" channel in redis-store pub-sub

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using `node.js`, `redis store` for `socket.io`.

While doing PUB-SUB I could see channel = `dispatch`

Hence need to understand this `dispath` channel, how it is connected to my node process and how PUB SUB is working internally.

Already gone through the [redis.io pub-sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) document but could not get dispatch channel.
Any other document could help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using the Redis store for `socket.io` as well? [Here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/5120a706f21d76ddbdc33a43100c7fee801a98dd/lib/manager.js#L316) is the relevant code in `socket.io` that creates a `dispatch` channel.

Comment: thanks for the reply, edited the question, you are correct, socket.io is the MAIN thing for which redis store was required. I will go through your link now.

Comment: to be frank, I could not understand much of the code, is `dispatch` fired for every broadcast in the room ? Thanks.

Comment: [The source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/5120a706f21d76ddbdc33a43100c7fee801a98dd/lib/manager.js#L380) says "*Called when a message is sent to a namespace and/or room*".